# Radon-Nikodym derivative and change of measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, expected-value, radon-nikodym

I was reading a work and an apparently simple proof is causing me technical troubles. The lemma is about differential entropy and change of measures.

Assume random variables with continuous and positive densities.

\begin{equation}
h(T(X)) = h(X) + E[\log(T'(X))],
\end{equation}
where $T$ is an increasing function (transportation map) such that $T(X^*)$ and $X$ have the same distribution.

The proof is quite short and goes like this:

We have that $p_{T(X)}(T(x))dT(x)= p_X(x)dx$ and thus:
$$h(T(X))= - E[\log(p_{T(X)}(T(X)))] = -E\left[\log\left(\frac{p_X(X)}{T'(X)}\right)\right].$$

I tried to fill in the gaps, and the missing step would be:
$$ P_{T(X)}(T(X))= P_X(X)\frac{dX}{dT(X)}, $$ but then, is it true that 
$$ \frac{dX}{dT(X)} = \frac{1}{T'(X)}?$$
Why? Does, in this case, the Radon-Nikodym derivative coincide with the usual derivative? Which technical steps am I missing?

Comment: What is h exactly

Comment: Differential entropy, i.e. given a continuous random variable $X$ with distribution $P_X$, $h(X)= -E[\log(P_X(X))]$.

Comment: They are doing an informal step in the "we have, thus" by dividing both sides with $dx$. You end up with density*derivative = density of X and result follows